# How to find $x$-intercept on TI-83/TI-84 calculator without having to set the bounds for each intercept?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, calculator

Finding $y$-intercepts is very easy on a TI-83/TI-84 calculator. All you have to do is graph the function and use `2nd` $\to$ `Trace` $\to$ `Value` $\to$ $x=0$.

However, the same method can't be used for finding the $x$-intercepts. The only way I know of finding the $x$-intercepts on these calculators is to use `2nd` $\to$ `Trace` $\to$ `zero/intersect` $\to$ and then select the left and right bounds of each intercept. Is there a way to find the $x$-intercepts immediately? Such as making a table that shows all the $x$-values for which $y$ equals zero?

Answer (score 2):

You can also draw the help function $y=0$. Then you can do `2nd` $\rightarrow$ `Trace` $\rightarrow$ `intersect`. You will have to select the two curves and do a guess, but I think it's still more convenient than giving left/right bounds.